# Проблема с отправкой сообщений через бота. Библиотека aiogram Python

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Почему у меня когда с помощью await state.set_state(name1) передаю сообщение в хендлер с функцией, в которой await state.set_state('name2) передает следующее сообщение в следующий хендлер, возникает проблема: если отправить одновременно два сообщения, то они обработаются оба в хендлере name1.

Но если отправить два по порядку, то все в норме и обратается сначала в первом хендлере, а следующее передастся во второй. В обоих применяется lock, но это не помогает.

То же самое происходит, если сначала отправить одно сообщение, оно обработается в первом хендлере. А если через несколько секунд отправить еще два одновременно, то опять таки оба обработаются во втором.

```
@dp.message_handler(state='message_in_chat')
async def send_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.forward_message(id, message.from_user.id,
                                      message.message_id)
    with dp.current_state(chat=message.chat.id, user=message.from_user.id) as state:
        await state.set_state('message_two')

@dp.message_handler(state='message_two')
async def send_message2(message: types.Message):
    await bot.forward_message(id, message.from_user.id,
                                          message.message_id)
    with dp.current_state(chat=message.chat.id, user=message.from_user.id) as state:
         await state.set_state('message_in_chat')
```

Comment: В первую функцию сообщение приходит из другой функции тем же методом.

Comment: Этот ответ может быть не точным, поскольку я нахожусь в процессе изучения python, но скорее всего это просто сама библиотека неправильно функционирует или установлена не актуальная версия (лично у меня было такое 2 раза, по одному на каждый случай). Советую обновить библиотеку или воспользоваться другой.

Comment: Нет, библиотека правильно установлена, дело не в этом.